# Successful Gradle project build produces NoClassDefFoundError at runtime

Tags: java, gradle

I am using Gradle to build my Java project in Eclipse. gradle.build is as follows

```
apply plugin: 'java'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.flowpowered', name: 'flow-nbt', version: '1.0.0'
    compile group: 'org.reflections', name: 'reflections', version: '0.9.10'
}
```

All libraries are functioning properly when run through Eclipse. But sometimes it is useful to work on the command line. When run on the command line, the runtime error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/flowpowered/nbt/regionfile/SimpleRegionFileReader` occurs, even though the build is successful and the code contains imports from those libraries. I have tried cleans and rebuilds, along with `gradlew build --refresh-dependencies`, but I still encounter the same runtime error.

I would assume that the libraries are just never actually imported? Or that they are not being stored where the java project thinks they are? I'm unfamiliar with Gradle, so any advice on this is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the posted `build.gradle` file you are not packaging the application as an executable JAR.

First apply the `application` plugin. But this will not be enough as you won't be able to run the executable as a single JAR without all of its dependencies. Apply the  `shadow` plugin too.

These two plugins will give you access to the following tasks:

- `run`: execute the application from gradle's command line.
- `runShadow`: execute the application but with all dependencies packaged in a  single JAR, alongside your compiled classes and resources.
- `shadowJar`: create a single "fat JAR" with compiled classes and all dependencies.

Thus your `build.gradle` may look like this

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '1.2.4'
}
mainClassName = 'com.acme.YourMainClassName'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.flowpowered', name: 'flow-nbt', version: '1.0.0'
    compile group: 'org.reflections', name: 'reflections', version: '0.9.10'
}
```

Plugin documentation:

- https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow
- https://docs.gradle.org/3.4/userguide/application_plugin.html#useApplicationPlugin

Answer (score 0):

Another solution without using any plugins and still end up with a runnable fat jar

```
jar {
    archiveName = 'NameOfYourApp.jar'

    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'uk.co.cdl.Main',
                'Class-Path': configurations.runtime.files.collect { "lib/$it.name" }.join(' '),
                'Implementation-Version': project.version
    }

    from(configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }) {
    include/exclude anything if need to if not take the curlys off 
    }
}
```